# Why is a monitor’s physical aspect ratio different from resolution aspect ratio for many displays?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, aspect-ratio

I recently purchased this monitor, a [Samsung UE57 Series 28-Inch 4K UHD (3840x2160)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FBNPTDD), and it turns out that the display area (620.93mm x 341.28mm) has a different aspect ratio (~1.82) than its resolution. The specified optimal resolution is 4K UHD, or 3840x2160, which is an aspect ratio of 16:9 (~1.78). This causes the images displayed in the monitor to be horizontally stretched by a tiny bit, and while it is not noticeable in daily use, is measurable. I tried measuring a circle's diameter on the screen horizontally and vertically, and there is a consistent difference between the two.

So I went to Amazon and was about to buy another monitor, a [BenQ EL2870U 28 inch 4K Monitor for Gaming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078HWN5CX), at a similar price, but then I noticed in [the spec sheet](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81cBLGWkHFL.pdf) that it too has exactly the same display area size and resolution.

So my questions are, is this a common practice among manufacturers? Are there any practical benefits for the manufacturer in doing things this way? Is there a way to correct this in software? (I use macOS and Linux)

I don’t think this will cause any practical problems for me, because I”m a software engineer and my main use for the monitor is writing code, not doing graphic design or anything else that requires precise shapes.

But nevertheless it does bother me that there is a subtle flaw in there and that everything I look at will be slightly squished.

Comment: There's native resolution, and then there's skewed. I don't know where you get the "optimal" resolution thing from, but on flat panels you have only one resolution that will keep things looking accurate: native resolution.

Comment: "Optimal" is what Samsung calls it on the product manual, but I think it's the native resolution as well. The stated maximum resolution is 3840x2160 and that's also the highest resolution shown by `xrandr --query` on Linux.

Comment: Maybe something to do with the RGB subpixels. Perhaps there are some technical limitations / reasons that prevent the vendors from producing panels with square pixels.

Comment: What is your display adapter?

Comment: @harrymc I'm on a 2020 Macbook Pro so Intel Iris Plus Graphics

Answer (score 0):

The display area having a different aspect ratio from the resolution
is a sign that the monitor pixels are not square, but rectangular.

Windows only knows about pixel resolution and assumes that the pixels
are square. So when it draws a perfect circle, it comes out a bit squashed
if the pixels are not perfectly square.
Monitors usually have square pixels, although my suspicion is that
in modern ultra high resolution and wide monitors, the pixels are not
perfectly square.

You may force a custom aspect ratio if you wish to correct the issue,
but you should know that using your native resolution is important
for good graphics quality and reducing computation, so using less
graphics horsepower. You also risk having black unused bands on the
monitor.

As you say that your main use for the monitor is writing code,
not graphic design or anything similar, I would recommend staying
with the native resolution. Not using the native resolution means that
pixels will smear and overflow, as it's impossible to display
sub-pixels, reducing the crispness of the code text.

Nevertheless, changing the aspect ratio is possible for NVIDIA adapters
by using the NVIDIA Control Panel. Other manufacturers may have
their own utilities.

You may read more about the subject in Wikipedia
[Pixel aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio).

Comment: Yeah I get worse quality when using non-native resolutions. MacOS's display scaling is good but I don't think it will keep looking as good if I try forcing a different aspect ratio. The unused bands would be distracting as well.

Comment: Since you have mostly answered my questions I'll award the bounty in a few hours unless there is another more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tl;Dr: the resolution assumes square pixels, but the physical led pixels are rectangular

Longer explanation:
Each pixel on the screen is built from 3 square LEDs next to each other. You can see a 4k screen under the microscope here: https://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/aLMqjLM_700b.jpg
And you can't put 3 squares in a square.
So the physical ratio is different from the computed ratio.

The computed ratio comes from historical reasons when the screen was squared and green, and the can have to go from top left and scan the screen all the time.

Comment: So the ultimate question might be, why aren't the LED made rectangular such that three of them can form a square...

Comment: The led itself is round so the smallest carrying board is square.

Comment: @EranGoldman So how are the LEDs arranged in screens with square pixels? Are square LEDs resulting in rectangular pixels easier to manufacture for high pixel density screens?